# ETH Accounts per block

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, accounts, rpc

Correct me if Im wrong but from my understanding each block has a "stateRoot" property that point to status of the State tree at the time of mining. I also believe that tha state tree contais a list of accounts (user accounts and contracts) and their balance\code.

Is it possible to get the list of accounts and their balance (if not contracts) on each block? I know I can use the "eth_getBalance" RPC call to get the ballance of each account but that wold require me to know before hand which are the accounts.

thanks

Comment: how do you want to get the balances, with Javascript through web3 or in golang?

Comment: blocks do not contain accounts, blocks contain transactions. accounts are stored in levelDB , so you can only get list of transactions for the block, and the `from` / `to` addresses where the money went on these transactions

Comment: @Nulik I am making RPC requests to geth so if possible I'd like to continue using that method. And yes, I know that the block only contains the to\from, thus my second point. Im just wondering if there is a way of queryng the state tree given the "stateRoot" of each block for example to get the balances of all the accounts on that block. Thanks

Comment: well, I am not using web3, but seems that it has all the calls. Kind of like web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(), then web3.eth.getBalance() for every 'from` or 'to'. No need to mess with stateRoot, it is more like low level stuff.

Comment: yes, that is my current aproach, get each transaction in a block than call getBalance for all accounts in to and from....I was just wondering if it was an easier way.  Speaking of which, I am facing this(https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39610/missing-trie-node-when-requesting-balance) problem now if you dont mind taking a look. Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe etherscan.io will suit you if you don't need much advanced stuff, they have an API and you don't need to sync. but sometimes it goes down, so if your app is kinda critical, you have to do it on your own node with full blockchain