# "missing trie node" when requesting balance

Tags: go-ethereum, balances, rinkeby

I've been getting the "missing trie node" error in the majority of my eth_getBalance requests if I use anything other than the "latest" block or very recent blocks. For example, the request:

```
"eth_getBalance", ['0x1cbff6551b8713296b0604705b1a3b76d238ae14', '0xf4251']
```

on the rinkeby network will return the error as 0xf4251 (1000017) is an old block (current is around 1.7M)

Other answers to this question suggets that I cant get the value because the state tree has been pruned so Im wondering if there is a way of getting the full tree?  Someone suggested using `--synmode=full` when starting get, but that didnt work.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From **`trie/errors.go`**:

```
package trie

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
)

// MissingNodeError is returned by the trie functions (TryGet, TryUpdate, TryDelete)
// in the case where a trie node is not present in the local database. It contains
// information necessary for retrieving the missing node.
type MissingNodeError struct {
    NodeHash common.Hash // hash of the missing node
    Path     []byte      // hex-encoded path to the missing node
}

func (err *MissingNodeError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("missing trie node %x (path %x)", err.NodeHash, err.Path)
}
```

You have to download full blockchain.

Comment: shouldn't synmode=full when running geth do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin,debug --syncmode full --gcmode=archive
```

both

> --syncmode full and --gcmode=archive will be work